# Master and content pages with javascript in asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi i'm very new to .net programming.I want to run a javascript from a content page containing a button. I'm able to display a button but dont know how to bind action. Help me in this regard.

Comment: What do you want the javascript to do? Handle the click of the button?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be easy to Attach a JavaScript function to the control by doing the following:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:JSFunctionName();" />
```

If you have a specific problem then let me know ?